# Text (font) looks faded on older apis

Tags: android, textview, android-typeface

I am using a custom typeface, and it displays perfectly on newer android versions(tested on API 17(Asus tab), 18(Dell tab), 19(Nex4) - devices). However, the same typeface looks faded (possibly distorted?) on older versions - API 8(SE X10i), 10(LG P500H).

Here's a comparison, in case my explanation doesn't make sense:

On nex4:

[image]

On x10i:

[image]

I am using a custom typeface with Typeface.BOLD:

```
tvTitle.setTypeface(titleAndBodyFont, Typeface.BOLD);
```

And the body ("Looks *" part):

```
tvBody.setTypeface(titleAndBodyFont);
```

XML declaration for title:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_title_side"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_title_side"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_title_top"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/constant_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_title" />
```

`tvBody` is declared in a similar fashion.

Is this a known bug? If so, could someone help me find the bug report? It would help knowing what version this was fixed in. If not, I would be grateful for a solution.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952894/custom-font-in-android-renders-differently-in-different-apis)?

Comment: @jenzz I did try that before posting this question. It made no difference. From what I can tell, the problem is coming from `Typeface.BOLD`, which I set on the title - `Testing font on ... ` part. The body text looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use 2 fonts, 1 normal and 1 bold. So when you need to go bold, just change your font. Never had problems, you can also create your custom textviewplus.

Something like this:

/res/values/attrs.xml

```
<resources>   
<attr name="fontFamily" format="enum">
    <enum name="helvetica" value="0"/>
    <enum name="helvetica_bold" value="1"/>
</attr>
```

your TextViewPlus:

```
public class TextViewPlus extends TextView{

private static final String TAG = "TextViewPlus";

public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
    int customFont = a.getInt(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_fontFamily, -1);
    setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
    a.recycle();
}

public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, int font) {
    Typeface tf = null;
    try {
    tf = Typefaces.get(ctx, font);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    setTypeface(tf);  
    return true;
}

public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
    Typeface tf = null;
    try {
    tf = Typefaces.get(ctx, asset);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    setTypeface(tf);
    return true;
}
```

}

How to use:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.myapp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <com.myapp.viewhelpers.TextViewPlus 
        app:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fontFamily="helvetica"
        android:text="helo world"/>
```

Comment: Well, I have been using this approach wherever I have access to both bold and regular versions of a font. But, in this particular case, I only have access to the regular version. It seems the only way to go is to procure the bold version of the font and use your solution. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't help you much, definitely looks like a bug, but to check the bug extension maybe you find this test useful:

```
        public class TestBoldText extends View {

            private TextPaint mPaint;

            public TestBoldText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

                super(context, attrs);

                mPaint = new TextPaint(); 


                mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
                mPaint.setFlags(mPaint.getFlags()|Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                super.onDraw(canvas);
                canvas.drawText("i am a bold text!", 0, 0, mPaint)

            }

        }
```

It looks like Android uses a "fake bold" approach to draw bold text, rather than a specific bold version of the typeface. I suppose they draw the same text with a pixel offset. This test draws acceptable bold text in my devices with API >= ICS (samsung galaxy / amazon kindle) but I'd be curious to know if it fails in your device as well, as I am doing kind of a wysiwig editor.

Also, `mPaint.setStrokeWidth` should change the text line width. I suppose playing with setStrokeWidth / setAntiAlias / setFakeBoldText you can get a decent bold text in the older API, but I also wonder why the result is not the same...

good luck in your investigation !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: It does fail on API 8 and 10. I'll be trying this approach on other api levels, but so far, bold on 17, 18, 19 works as expected. Here is the output from the test class you posted: [Link](http://ge.tt/9YF4TRS1/v/0?c). Thanks again for your input. +1

Comment: good to know, so if Google's methods for programmatically setting Bold do fail, I think this is definitely a bug. I wonder if they will fix it though ... I think google guys only want to hear about kitkat nowadays!