# Text is not looking right on some devices while using custom font

Tags: android, textview, android-typeface

I have made an application. My application is using the custom fonts to be applied on the text views to show text in specific style. All thing was working good and looking impressive Until I tried my app on Samsung 10" device.

On 10' tablet I saw my text is not even readable and not looking cool. Its just got cut from bottom and from top. And some words are overlapping each other.

Where as 7" tablet is showing this good. and there is no problem of any sort of in other device.

So this means that custom font file is not damaged.

**So my questions are:**

1) Why 10' tablet is not showing the text right when I applied the typeface and custom font. But When I remove the custom font type face its all start looking cool.

2) what is a way to set the typeface (Custom font) to be look good in all devices. ?

please help me. It is the last thing I have to do in my app.

Comment: Make sure you use **sp** for text sizes, not **px** or any other units.

Comment: and You have declared different dimen.xml for multiple screen sizes?

Comment: how it is going to help me in the custom type face @Opiatefuchs

Comment: I mean, do You have set different font size for different screen sizes?

Comment: Short explanation: SP stands for Scale-Independant-Pixels. This unit causes the font to be scaled by the users font size in device preference.This could cause the behaviour that You described. If You go to Your device settings and make this settings smaller or bigger, You will se it has an effect.

Comment: i have tried setting the larger and smaller kind of different num of sp of text size but nothing helped me

Comment: show this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337907/text-font-looks-faded-on-older-apis?rq=1

Comment: Hello @AllayKhalil did you solved your issue? if yes, can you please provide solutions?